# Change PATH Environment Variable in MAMP

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I need to update my **PATH** variable within a **[MAMP v3.4](https://www.mamp.info/en/)** server.

As you can see, the **PATH** environment variable that Apache is using does not match the **PATH** that I use when I open terminal.

```php
<?php
  passthru('env');
  die();
```

The script above prints out:

```
...
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
...
```

Meanwhile, my **PATH** when I run my terminal is:

```
$ env
  ...
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have tried the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110634/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-mamp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256008/setting-environment-variables-in-mamp), but none have worked.

Setting an environment variable in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` seemed promising, but it doesn't work when setting **PATH**.

```
# Near the top of my httpd.conf file...
SetEnv MY_TEST_DETAIL foo
SetEnv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I restart my MAMP server, and looked at `phpinfo()`

[image: Apache Environment Variables]

As you can see, it added the **MY_TEST_DETAIL** environment variable, but it did not change **PATH**.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with MAMP 4.0.6.  I've been looking around and have yet to find a working solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MAMP 4.0.6 for OSX I was able to update the Apache Environment Path by doing the following:

First check `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl` for a line with the comment:

```
#pick up any necessary environment variables
```

Just below this line you should see a path to where MAMP will load environment variables.

Mine said:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars
```

In the `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin` path you should see a file named `envvars_`.

Copy this file and rename to `envvars` and add the following line:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Now restart your MAMP servers.  The phpinfo should now have the updated path information.

Comment: I thought I tried this before and found it didn't work (Apache wouldn't even start). After fiddling with it some more, I got it to work by commenting out the `if test "x$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"` block along with the final `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` command. So, my `envvars` file basically just contains `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` at the bottom. Now, my **PATH** environment variable is changed. Thanks! Works for me.

Comment: God bless you! I had already changed that file but renaming it was what I was missing

Comment: In case some desperate soul like me reaches here, the binary executables I needed were homebrew installed so I also had to add `/opt/homebrew/bin`